# Matching a character when it occurs once or three times

Tags: javascript, regex

I work on some matching (regex for JavaScript) related to markdown. I need to match if a `_` or `*` occurs once (at the beginning, end or followed and preceded by other chars or whitespace) and if that happens with 3 `_` or `*` (`___` or `***`). But not two.

So a match would be `*` but also `***` but not `**a` or but `**_` would be a match for `_`.

So I basically want to match if an element is italic in markdown (`*italic*`) or bold and italic (`***bold italic***`). It could also be `_** italic bold **_`.

I am here at the moment, but it does not really work. Also if at anyway possible I would like to have it match this in only 2 or even better only one regex.

```
(^|[^_])_([^_]|$)
(^|[^_])_([^_]|$)
(^|[^\*])\*([^\*]|$)
(^|[^\*])\*\*\*([^\*]|$)
```

// EDIT

Matching inputs for `*****`

```
*em*
***em***
__*em*
__*em*__
word*em*word
```

Not matching for `*****`

```
**em**
****em****
```

Comment: Can you give examples of matching and non-matching inputs?

Comment: Added some inputs that would and would not match.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I need regex for Javascript.

Comment: Okay, and what how should `*em***` be treated?

Comment: Well, either two matches (* and ***) and I figured it out in the code afterwards or the perfect solution would be to only match `*em*` or `***em***` it could match `*em*** some words*`. But if I get all matches with the positions listed, I am already a step farther. :)

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? Especially with weird `***stars***`?

Comment: What do you mean reinventing? I just need to match markdown and \*\*\*text\*\*\* is correct markdown syntax. I need to match to remove the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bases on what I understood I believe this regex should work:

```
(?:^|[^*])_*([*](?:[*]{2})*)?[^*_]+\1_*(?:[^*]|$)
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/qX5gR5

Comment: It is nearly perfect but it also matches _em* and it only matches if it is the whole line. I need to match it within a text so `text *em* text` needs to be a match as well. BUT `*em_`is not a match.

Comment: So `__*em*` is valid but `*em_` is not?

Comment: Cool, could you update it to match **_em_** as well? Thank you so much already.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will have to fiddle with it a bit, but this helps  me a lot.